# Problemas para interactuar con estructuras de clases padres en clases herederas de C++

Tags: c++, poo, estructuras-de-datos

*[Aquí](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a9qP5ZNUFPprmxYShsxO4JM17BiR_sPgrlQuk4mvICY/edit?usp=sharing) está el código del programa, el cual no me permite interactuar con las estructuras de las clases padres en clases hijas*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class clas_menu {
public:
    clas_menu();
    int met_mostrar_opciones();
    int atr_opcion;
};

class clas_registrar_libros {
public:
    clas_registrar_libros();
    std::string atr_autor, atr_anho, atr_titulo;
    int atr_cantidad;
    void met_registrar();

protected:
    struct Libro {
        std::string atr_autor;
        std::string atr_anho;
        std::string atr_titulo;
        int atr_cantidad;
    };

    std::vector<Libro> libros;
};

class clas_registrar_usuarios {
public:
    clas_registrar_usuarios();
    std::string atr_nombres, atr_apellidos, atr_identificacion, atr_anho_usu;
    void met_registrar_usuario();

protected:
    struct Usuario {
        std::string atr_nombres;
        std::string atr_apellidos;
        std::string atr_identificacion;
        std::string atr_anho_usu;
    };

    std::vector<Usuario> usuarios;
};

class clas_prestar_libros : public clas_registrar_libros {
public:
    clas_prestar_libros();
    void met_prestar_libros();
    std::string atr_pautor, atr_panho, atr_ptitulo;

};

class clas_buscar_libros : public clas_registrar_libros {
public:
    clas_buscar_libros();
    void met_buscar_libros();
};

class clas_eliminar_libros : public clas_registrar_libros {
public:
    clas_eliminar_libros();
    std::string atr_titulo1, atr_autor1, atr_anho1;
    void met_eliminar_libros();
};

class clas_devolver_libros : public clas_registrar_libros {
public:
    clas_devolver_libros();
    std::string atr_librod, atr_autord, atr_anhod;
    void met_devolver_libros();
};

class clas_mostrar_registros : public clas_registrar_libros, public clas_registrar_usuarios {
public:
    clas_mostrar_registros();
    void met_mostrar_registros();

};

clas_menu::clas_menu() {

}

int clas_menu::met_mostrar_opciones() {
    clas_registrar_libros obj_registrar;
    clas_registrar_usuarios obj_registrarusuario;
    clas_prestar_libros obj_prestar_libros;
    clas_buscar_libros obj_buscar_libros;
    clas_eliminar_libros obj_administrar;
    clas_devolver_libros obj_devolver;
    clas_mostrar_registros obj_mostrar_registros;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Menú de opciones: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Registrar libros. Opción 1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Registrar usuarios. Opción 2" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. Prestar libros. Opción 3" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. Buscar libros. Opción 4" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. Administrar libros. Opción 5" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6. Devolver libros. Opción 6" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "7. Mostrar registros. Opción 7" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Ingrese su opción: ";
        std::cin >> atr_opcion;
        std::cin.ignore(); // Ignorar el carácter de nueva línea dejado por cin

        switch (atr_opcion) {
        case 1: {
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado registrar libros" << std::endl;
            obj_registrar.met_registrar();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado registrar usuarios" << std::endl;
            obj_registrarusuario.met_registrar_usuario();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado prestar libros" << std::endl;
            obj_prestar_libros.met_prestar_libros();
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado buscar libros" << std::endl;
            obj_buscar_libros.met_buscar_libros();
            break;
        case 5:
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado administración de libros" << std::endl;
            obj_administrar.met_eliminar_libros();
            break;
        case 6:
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado devolver libros" << std::endl;
            obj_devolver.met_devolver_libros();
            break;
        case 7:
            std::cout << "Has seleccionado mostrar registros" << std::endl;
            obj_mostrar_registros.met_mostrar_registros();
            return 0;
        default:
            std::cout << "La opción seleccionada no se encuentra en las mostradas anteriormente" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

clas_registrar_libros::clas_registrar_libros() {

}

void clas_registrar_libros::met_registrar() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el título del libro a ingresar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_titulo);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el autor del libro a ingresar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_autor);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el año del libro a ingresar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_anho);

    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        if (libros[i].atr_titulo == atr_titulo && libros[i].atr_autor == atr_autor && libros[i].atr_anho == atr_anho) {
            // El libro ya está registrado, incrementar la cantidad
            libros[i].atr_cantidad++;
            std::cout << "El libro ya estaba registrado. Se ha incrementado la cantidad." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    Libro libro;
    libro.atr_autor = atr_autor;
    libro.atr_anho = atr_anho;
    libro.atr_titulo = atr_titulo;
    libro.atr_cantidad = 1;

    libros.push_back(libro);

    std::cout << "El libro ha sido registrado exitosamente" << std::endl;
}

clas_registrar_usuarios::clas_registrar_usuarios() {

}

void clas_registrar_usuarios::met_registrar_usuario() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el nombre del usuario a registrar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_nombres);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el apellido del usuario a registrar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_apellidos);
    std::cout << "Ingrese la identificación del usuario a registrar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_identificacion);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el año de registro del usuario: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_anho_usu);

    for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
        if (usuarios[i].atr_identificacion == atr_identificacion) {
            // El usuario ya está registrado
            std::cout << "El usuario ya está registrado" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    Usuario usuario;
    usuario.atr_nombres = atr_nombres;
    usuario.atr_apellidos = atr_apellidos;
    usuario.atr_identificacion = atr_identificacion;
    usuario.atr_anho_usu = atr_anho_usu;

    usuarios.push_back(usuario);

    std::cout << "El usuario ha sido registrado exitosamente" << std::endl;
}

clas_prestar_libros::clas_prestar_libros() {

}

void clas_prestar_libros::met_prestar_libros() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el título del libro a prestar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_ptitulo);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el autor del libro a prestar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_pautor);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el año del libro a prestar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_panho);

    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        if (libros[i].atr_titulo == atr_ptitulo && libros[i].atr_autor == atr_pautor && libros[i].atr_anho == atr_panho) {
            if (libros[i].atr_cantidad > 0) {
                libros[i].atr_cantidad--;
                std::cout << "El libro ha sido prestado exitosamente" << std::endl;
                return;
            } else {
                std::cout << "No hay ejemplares disponibles de ese libro para prestar" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "No se encontró el libro solicitado" << std::endl;
}

clas_buscar_libros::clas_buscar_libros() {

}

void clas_buscar_libros::met_buscar_libros() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el título del libro a buscar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_titulo);

    bool encontrado = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        if (libros[i].atr_titulo == atr_titulo) {
            std::cout << "Libro encontrado:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Título: " << libros[i].atr_titulo << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Autor: " << libros[i].atr_autor << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Año: " << libros[i].atr_anho << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Cantidad disponible: " << libros[i].atr_cantidad << std::endl;
            encontrado = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!encontrado) {
        std::cout << "No se encontró el libro solicitado" << std::endl;
    }
}

clas_eliminar_libros::clas_eliminar_libros() {

}

void clas_eliminar_libros::met_eliminar_libros() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el título del libro a eliminar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_titulo1);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el autor del libro a eliminar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_autor1);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el año del libro a eliminar: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_anho1);

    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        if (libros[i].atr_titulo == atr_titulo1 && libros[i].atr_autor == atr_autor1 && libros[i].atr_anho == atr_anho1) {
            libros.erase(libros.begin() + i);
            std::cout << "El libro ha sido eliminado exitosamente" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "No se encontró el libro solicitado" << std::endl;
}

clas_devolver_libros::clas_devolver_libros() {

}

void clas_devolver_libros::met_devolver_libros() {
    std::cout << "Ingrese el título del libro a devolver: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_librod);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el autor del libro a devolver: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_autord);
    std::cout << "Ingrese el año del libro a devolver: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, atr_anhod);

    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        if (libros[i].atr_titulo == atr_librod && libros[i].atr_autor == atr_autord && libros[i].atr_anho == atr_anhod) {
            libros[i].atr_cantidad++;
            std::cout << "El libro ha sido devuelto exitosamente" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "No se encontró el libro solicitado" << std::endl;
}

clas_mostrar_registros::clas_mostrar_registros() {

}

void clas_mostrar_registros::met_mostrar_registros() {
    std::cout << "Registros de libros:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Título: " << libros[i].atr_titulo << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Autor: " << libros[i].atr_autor << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Año: " << libros[i].atr_anho << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Cantidad disponible: " << libros[i].atr_cantidad << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Registros de usuarios:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Nombre: " << usuarios[i].atr_nombres << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Apellido: " << usuarios[i].atr_apellidos << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Identificación: " << usuarios[i].atr_identificacion << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Año de registro: " << usuarios[i].atr_anho_usu << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    clas_menu obj_menu;
    obj_menu.met_mostrar_opciones();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Supongo que no te dejaba cargar el código. Ahora para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida, dinos cuál es el problema y cuál es el comportamiento esperado. En otras palabras, crea un [mre].

Comment: El problema está en por ejemplo en la clase prestar libros, así ingresé los mismos parámetros que tenga la estructura con elementos previamente agregados, me aparece que el libro no fue encontrado o simplemente no interactúa con estructuras de control como if y for para poder manipular el arreglo en los diferentes métodos de las clases

Comment: Como creo un ejemplo minimo verificable? soy nuevo en la plataforma